# Разбор строки JSON, загруженной из CSV с использованием Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

Коллеги, мучаюсь с такой задачей: есть csv файл такого типа:

```
1;{'BT3': ['1.667', 13, '1:2 02:27', 7.61], 'PAC': ['1.4', 15, '1:2 (1:2) 22:00', None], 'BCT': ['1.49', 0, '1:2 (1:2) 00:02', 7.93], 'WLN': ['1.44', 7, '1:2 (1:2)', 11.46], 'LIG': ['1.37', 3, '1:2 (1:2)', 7.96]};a44ab8cf2f9334b2d1;TEAM_TOTALS;P2__TOTALS__OVER(2.5)

2;{'BT3': ['1.667', 17, '1:2 02:32', 7.61], 'PAC': ['1.4', 19, '1:2 (1:2) 22:00', None], 'BCT': ['1.49', 4, '1:2 (1:2) 00:06', 7.93], 'WLN': ['1.44', 11, '1:2 (1:2)', 11.46], 'LIG': ['1.37', 7, '1:2 (1:2)', 7.96]};a44ab8cf2f9334b2d1;TEAM_TOTALS;P2__TOTALS__OVER(2.5)

3;{'BT3': ['1.667', 20, '1:2 02:35', 7.61], 'PAC': ['1.4', 22, '1:2 (1:2) 22:00', None], 'BCT': ['1.49', 7, '1:2 (1:2) 00:02', 7.93], 'WLN': ['1.44', 14, '1:2 (1:2)', 11.46], 'LIG': ['1.37', 10, '1:2 (1:2)', 7.96]};a44ab8cf2f9334b2d1;TEAM_TOTALS;P2__TOTALS__OVER(2.5)
```

Никак не получается корректно разбить на столбцы с применением pandas.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Попытался так:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'file.csv', converters={'json_column_name': eval})
```

очень некорректно делает разбивку по столбцам и еще первую строку выносит в заголовки.

Comment: А что вы хотите, чтобы получилось, какого формата датафрейм? Что-то не очень понятно.

Comment: разделители тут `;` соотвественно и разбивка будет такая

Comment: самое важное получить разбивку по столбцам этой подстроки: {'BT3': ['1.667', 13, '1:2 02:27', 7.61], 'PAC': ['1.4', 15, '1:2 (1:2) 22:00', None], 'BCT': ['1.49', 0, '1:2 (1:2) 00:02', 7.93], 'WLN': ['1.44', 7, '1:2 (1:2)', 11.46], 'LIG': ['1.37', 3, '1:2 (1:2)', 7.96]}

Answer (score 0):

Как вам уже подсказали, во время чтения файла нужно указать разделитель `;`. Если не хотите, чтобы элементы первой строки становились названием столбцов, то это тоже укажите (`header=None`):

```
In [60]: import pandas as pd

In [61]: import ast

In [62]: df = pd.read_csv('json_column.csv', sep=';', header=None, converters={1: ast.literal_eval})

In [63]: df
Out[63]: 
   0                                                  1                   2  \
0  1  {'BT3': ['1.667', 13, '1:2 02:27', 7.61], 'PAC...  a44ab8cf2f9334b2d1   
1  2  {'BT3': ['1.667', 17, '1:2 02:32', 7.61], 'PAC...  a44ab8cf2f9334b2d1   
2  3  {'BT3': ['1.667', 20, '1:2 02:35', 7.61], 'PAC...  a44ab8cf2f9334b2d1   

             3                      4  
0  TEAM_TOTALS  P2__TOTALS__OVER(2.5)  
1  TEAM_TOTALS  P2__TOTALS__OVER(2.5)  
2  TEAM_TOTALS  P2__TOTALS__OVER(2.5)
```

На данном этапе, элементы колонки `1` являются словарями. Далее нужно распарсить их. Для этого можно воспользоваться [`pandas.json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
In [64]: pd.json_normalize(df[1])
Out[64]: 
                            BT3                               PAC  \
0  [1.667, 13, 1:2 02:27, 7.61]  [1.4, 15, 1:2 (1:2) 22:00, None]   
1  [1.667, 17, 1:2 02:32, 7.61]  [1.4, 19, 1:2 (1:2) 22:00, None]   
2  [1.667, 20, 1:2 02:35, 7.61]  [1.4, 22, 1:2 (1:2) 22:00, None]   

                                BCT                           WLN  \
0  [1.49, 0, 1:2 (1:2) 00:02, 7.93]   [1.44, 7, 1:2 (1:2), 11.46]   
1  [1.49, 4, 1:2 (1:2) 00:06, 7.93]  [1.44, 11, 1:2 (1:2), 11.46]   
2  [1.49, 7, 1:2 (1:2) 00:02, 7.93]  [1.44, 14, 1:2 (1:2), 11.46]   

                           LIG  
0   [1.37, 3, 1:2 (1:2), 7.96]  
1   [1.37, 7, 1:2 (1:2), 7.96]  
2  [1.37, 10, 1:2 (1:2), 7.96]
```

Объединим эти столбцы с основным датафреймом:

```
In [65]: df.drop(1, axis='columns').join(pd.json_normalize(df[1]))
Out[65]: 
   0                   2            3                      4  \
0  1  a44ab8cf2f9334b2d1  TEAM_TOTALS  P2__TOTALS__OVER(2.5)   
1  2  a44ab8cf2f9334b2d1  TEAM_TOTALS  P2__TOTALS__OVER(2.5)   
2  3  a44ab8cf2f9334b2d1  TEAM_TOTALS  P2__TOTALS__OVER(2.5)   

                            BT3                               PAC  \
0  [1.667, 13, 1:2 02:27, 7.61]  [1.4, 15, 1:2 (1:2) 22:00, None]   
1  [1.667, 17, 1:2 02:32, 7.61]  [1.4, 19, 1:2 (1:2) 22:00, None]   
2  [1.667, 20, 1:2 02:35, 7.61]  [1.4, 22, 1:2 (1:2) 22:00, None]   

                                BCT                           WLN  \
0  [1.49, 0, 1:2 (1:2) 00:02, 7.93]   [1.44, 7, 1:2 (1:2), 11.46]   
1  [1.49, 4, 1:2 (1:2) 00:06, 7.93]  [1.44, 11, 1:2 (1:2), 11.46]   
2  [1.49, 7, 1:2 (1:2) 00:02, 7.93]  [1.44, 14, 1:2 (1:2), 11.46]   

                           LIG  
0   [1.37, 3, 1:2 (1:2), 7.96]  
1   [1.37, 7, 1:2 (1:2), 7.96]  
2  [1.37, 10, 1:2 (1:2), 7.96]
```

Элементы новых столбцов - списки. Их тоже можно как-то обработать, но вы не уточнили какой вид вам нужен.

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ!